# Inverse element of the abelian group (P(M),symmetric difference)

Tags: abelian-groups

What would be the inverse element in this abelian group: $(P(M),\triangle)$?
I know the neutral element is the empty set and I thought the inverse element would be $A^{c}$ for every $A$. Turns out $A\triangle A^{c}=P(M)$ but it has to return the empty set.

Comment: P(M) means power set of M

Comment: A set $B$ with $A\Delta B=\emptyset$ must have every point in $A\cup B$ also in $A\cap B$. This would work, for instance, if $A\cup B=A\cap B=A...$ (in fact this is the only possibility, since $A\cap B\subset A\subset A\cup B$.) Can you think of any sets like that?

Comment: also consider what is the inverse of the neutral element $\varnothing$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The inverse element for every $A \in P(M)$ is A itself!

Because: $A \triangle A=(A\cup A)\backslash (A\cap A)=A\backslash A=\varnothing$